# How can i get user data in nextjs before rendering main app only first time then dispatch redux action?

Tags: react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, next-auth

I want to load user data in redux store only when app is loaded first time
but in serverside and use those data throughout the any page of the app.

I have implemented this and this is working but i don't know this is the best practice or efficient. I am looking for if there is any standard or better implementation.
Here is my `store.ts` files:

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action, combineReducers, AnyAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import authSlice from '../Modules/Auth/authSlice'


const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  user: authSlice
});

const reducer = (state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state, // use previous state
      ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
    };
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};



export function makeStore() {
  return configureStore({
    reducer,
  })
}

const store = makeStore()

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  AppState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>

export default store

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

Here is my app file:

`pages/_app.tsx`

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import '../../public/assets/css/bootstrap.css'
import '../../public/assets/css/common.css'
import '../../public/assets/css/main.css'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

import store, { wrapper } from '../app/store'
import { setUser } from '../Modules/Auth/authSlice'
import axios from 'axios'
import { BASE_URL } from '../../utils/axios/useAPI'


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  store.dispatch(setUser(pageProps.user));
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialAppProps(
  store => async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
    console.log('inside _app init app props')
    let userData: {};
    try {
      const result = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        withCredentials: true,
        url: `${BASE_URL}teacher/auth/getUser`,
        headers: ctx.req ? { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie } : undefined
      })
      userData = result.data;
    } catch (e) {
      userData = null;
    }
    return {
      pageProps: {
        // Call page-level getInitialProps
        // DON'T FORGET TO PROVIDE STORE TO PAGE
        ...(Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps({ ...ctx, store }) : {}),
        // Some custom thing for all pages
        pathname: ctx.pathname,
        user: userData
      },
    };
  }
);

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp)
```

Also I am curios to know that can I implement `next-auth` for this scenario?
kinda confused how to do with next-auth.
If possible please include an example.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi can you pls explain what solution you have found for this?